# how to restart a subsystem in alfresco 4 community?

Tags: authentication, tomcat, alfresco, openldap

i'm working in installing and configuring Alfresco community edition 4 (alfresco-community-4.0.d-installer-linux-x64.bin) on a 64bit ubuntu server (10.04.4 LTS). I'm trying to authenticate and syncronize users and group with out OpenLDAP server but as long as we make changes to
`$TOMCAT_HOME/shared/classes/alfresco/extension/subsystems/Authentication/ldap/ldap1/ldap-authentication.properties`
i have to restart tomcat or the whole server.

Is there a way to restart only a single subsytem in alfresco community edition?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, not. The reason is that JMX, which allows you to restart subsystems without a restart, is only available in Enterprise Edition.